# php match pattern to get images from text file

Tags: php, regex

i have seen many answers when people ask how to grab and extract the images actual  URLs, from a web page content / text ect, however, in my database, sadly, i have this syntax:

```
&lt;img class=&quot;photo&quot; src=&quot;http://domain.com/image.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;alt goes here&quot; /&gt;
```

So, the typical way `$pattern = '/src=["|\']([^"|\']+)/is';` does not work in my case due to those "...
Have been trying for hours, i must be doing something very very wrong...
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you first `str_replace` all that, then use your regex?

Comment: Because `str_replace` is not safe? **Why even bother writing an HTML decoder and parser in PHP, when PHP does it already just by calling the right function??**

Comment: @ChristianSciberras - Seems like you misunderstood me: I said he should [first run `str_replace` on his string](http://codepad.org/QekMM6IG), then use his regex!

Comment: @JosephSilber Actually, you misunderstood what I meant. The OP should not decode the HTML manually (using `str_replace`). Because, for example, his HTML might contain `&#34` or `&#x22`, both of which have the same effect of `&quot;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dont use Regular expression!**

Use XML/DOM libraries like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net).

BTW, the regular expression you are looking for is,

```
$pattern = '/src=(["\'])(.+)(?=\1)/i';
```

---

**Test Case (Optional):**

Here is a simple program to test it. Obviously you need to use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` first to decode it from entity format.

```
$str = array(
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"script.js\"></script>",
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src='script.js'></script>",
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>',
    '<script type="text/javascript" src=\'script.js\'></script>',
);
$pattern = '/src=(["\'])(.+)(?=\1)/i';

foreach($str as $s){
    preg_match($pattern, $s, $m);
    echo $m[2], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
script.js
script.js
script.js
script.js
```

Comment: @mario I see, my mistake. Thought it was another case of regex fanboyism.

Comment: Okie. Update the question according to OP. @mario.

Comment: Thank you ALL guys, i followed your advice on htmlspecialchars_decode and at last i have valid images URLS! `if ( preg_match( $pattern2, htmlspecialchars_decode($ck['post']), $found_img ) )`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the 'usual way' is to use an HTML/XML parser, not regular expressions.

Secondly, what you have is HTML code encoded as HTML text, which smells badly for two reasons:

- it's not HTML any more (why encode it as HTML text when it is in fact HTML code)?
- you shouldn't encode HTML before putting it into DB, but rather when writing it to the user.

With these two issues aside, what you need to do is to `htmlspecialchars_decode()` that stuff and pass it through an HTML parser:

```
$stuff = '&lt;img class=&quot;photo&quot; src=&quot;http://domain.com/image.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;alt goes here&quot; /&gt;';
$code = htmlspecialchars_decode($stuff, ENT_QUOTES);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($code);
```

That said, to me this sounds like a hack to fix badly written code. But there may be a valid reason why it's there in the first place.

Comment: `'&lt;img class=&quot;photo&quot; src=&quot;http://domain.com/image.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;alt goes here&quot; /&gt;';` is a dummy sample to show the way thousand different urls are found in my database. My problem is to ISOLATE the actual images location each time

Comment: @Andrew My point was that the stuff you have in your database hasn't been done correctly. First of, you don't encode HTML into HTML text, secondly, a database works best when the stuff is divided in columns and tables rather than blobs of data. You can use my code to do what you want nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you all very much for suggestions, @Christian Sciberras thank you, its not my code, i m not a guru just a newbie trying to fix something bought that does not work as intended... Blame Invision IPB for this type of db contents, all this happens when authorized users post html (where allowed to post html directly in post). I have this situation in my hands, its like that, and cant change it. Must deal with it and find the regular expression that will recognize the images URLs :)

Comment: Well then, IPB hasn't been designed that nicely. Not a surprise though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can test Regex here:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

What's not working?

Comment: First of all, double quotes are converted to `&quot;` just as other special characters, secondly, `preg_match` *definitely isn't a solution here*.

Comment: @ChristianSciberras, Alright, I didn't see the encoding in the original post. Nice answer!